# How do I assign a function to a global variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to pass the name of a javascript function to a global variable. I have a generic "CallMyWebService" function built around $.ajax(). The function's url, verb, contenttype, etc. are set based on the value of global variables. Immediately before the service function is called, the globals are set and after the globals reset to nothing.

My generic "CallMyWebService" function is here:

```
function CallMyWebService() { 

    $.ajax(
        {
        url         : varUrl,
        type        : varHttpVerb,
        cache       : varCacheBool,
        data        : varData, 
        contentType : varContentType,
        processdata : varProcessData, 
        dataType    : varDataType, 
        async       : varAsync,
        success     : varOnSuccess,
        error       : varOnError,
        complete    : varOnComplete
        }
    )

}
```

The problem I'm having is passing the function names to `varOnSuccess`, `varOnError`, and `varOnComplete`. If I have a function named `SuccessCallback()` and I want the the `result` of the service call passed to `SuccessCallback()`, how do I assign it to the `varOnSuccess` global variable? The variable assignment will take place in another function called `SetupServiceCall()`. In other words, in the `SetupServiceCall()` function how should `varOnSuccess =` be completed?

Comment: Are you really prefixing all variable *names* with `var`?!

Comment: @ThiefMaster - Yes and we're in maintenance mode so we're doing as little as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say:

```
varOnSuccess = SuccessCallback;
```

Look in the jQuery documentation for details on the parameters that SuccessCallback() will receive.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed the immediate issue. Although I feel Jordan's solution (pass the vales into a function) is preferred, sometimes you just need to apply bandages and keep on moving.

Answer (score 2):

CallMyWebService should accept those functions as parameters. You should also pass them by reference, instead of by string names.

Don't do a global variable. If you have any sort of parallel calls, this will fail.

Example:

```
function CallMyWebService(successCallback, errorCallback) {
    $.ajax(
        ...
        success: successCallback,
        error: errorCallback
        ...
    );
}

//calling the service
function MySuccessHandler(data) {
    alert('success');
}

function MyErrorHandler(data) {
    alert('error');
}

CallMyWebService(MySuccessHandler, MyErrorHandler);
```

Answer (score 0):

you mean like:

```
var varOnSuccess = null;
function SetupServiceCall() {
   varOnSuccess = SuccessCallback; //note 
}
```

?

Comment: you use the var keyword to indicate that a variable is not global.

Comment: @joidegn that's not necessarily true. Any var declared outside of a function will be global.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the function names without parenthesis in your ajax call, for example:

```
$.ajax({
...
success: SuccessCallback,
error: ErrorCallback,
...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.varOnSuccess = SuccessCallback
```

should work

However, I think it would be better to pass the variable parts to CallMyWebService as arguments like so:

```
function CallMyWebService(varSuccess, varError) { 

    $.ajax({
        url         : varUrl,
        type        : varHttpVerb,
        cache       : varCacheBool,
        data        : varData, 
        contentType : varContentType,
        processdata : varProcessData, 
        dataType    : varDataType, 
        async       : varAsync,
        success     : varSuccess,
        error       : varError,
        complete    : varOnComplete
    });

}
```